# Passing user id and vote id to a comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a new rails developer and i am currently working on a project, where users can post arguments to votes. (or comments to posts)
I have a devise user model, a votes model and a arguments model.

My problem is that i can't seem to access the users attributes, so i can add the `<%= argument.user.first_name %>` to a argument in my view.
My problem is that the argument.user.first_name returns this error : `undefined method`first_name' for nil:NilClass`

When i try with `<%= argument.vote.title %>` it works perfect.

When i go to the console and find the vote and the argument and do `argument.user.first_name` i get the correct first name.

The migration looks like this:

```
 create_table "arguments", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "argument"
    t.integer  "vote_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

So i have the foreign key from both users and votes in the arguments table.

I added a "has_many" relationships on both votes and users.  So both users and votes has_many :arguments.

My arguments controller looks like this:

```
    class ArgumentsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :current_user

    def create
        @vote = Vote.find(params[:vote_id])
        @argument = @vote.arguments.build(params[:argument].permit(:argument))
        @argument.user_id = current_user.id

        @argument.save!

        if @argument.save
            redirect_to @vote
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
        def argument_params
            params.require(:argument).permit(:title, :argument)

        end
end
```

I find the vote with the id and create the comment on that vote.
Im trying to pass the user_id, so i am able to access the users table, like picture, first_name ect.

My arguments _form:

```
<div class="well clearfix">
                    <h2>Tilføj et argument</h2>


<%= form_for([@vote, @vote.arguments.build]) do |f| %>

                    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id %>

                    <p><%= f.label :Bruger %><br>
                    <%= current_user.first_name %>

                    <p><%= f.label :Titel %><br>
                    <%= f.text_field :title %></p>

                    <p><%= f.label :Argument %><br>
                    <%= f.text_area :argument %>

                    <p><%= f.submit 'Opret', class: 'btn btn-primary' %></p>
                    <% end %>

                </div>
```

I build the argument with the vote_id
and display it with _arguments:

```
     <% @vote.arguments.each do |argument| %>
    <%= div_for(argument, class: 'col-md-4 well clearfix') do |argument| %>

              <h2><%= argument.title %></h2>


              <%= argument.argument %>
            <p>Af:
            <%= argument.user_id %>

            <%= argument.user.first_name %>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To me it seems like the user_id is not correctly passed with the create argument method?

In my routes i made the arguments as nested resources for votes:

```
    devise_scope :user do 
    resources :users, only: [:show]
  end

    root 'votes#index'
      resources :votes do
        resources :arguments
      end
```

Hope one of you can help me out and guide me in the right direction!
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh finally!  I managed to solve my own dumb problem.

The probem was that i was rendering the form (to create an argument) BEFORE the arguments.  This created an empty argument div/object, which does not contain anything.  So the error was constantly on that empty object (which obv did'nt contain user information, since it was empty)

So you answers were correct, but my question was wrong, haha
Well, thanks for your time!

In my show.html erb i added

```
        <%= render 'arguments/argument' %>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <%= render 'arguments/form' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to authenticate user in controller like:-

```
 before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Change argument controller:-

```
class ArgumentsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def create
        @vote = Vote.find(params[:vote_id])
        @argument = @vote.arguments.build(argument_params)
        if @argument.save
            redirect_to @vote
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def argument_params
        params.require(:argument).permit(:title, :argument, :user_id)
    end
end
```

arguments form change @current_user to current_user:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

Also you don't need to send user id in hidden field, because we can get current user in controller if user signed in, then you can assign user_id for argument in controller like:-

```
@argument.user_id = current_user.id
```

Comment: Better not to pass `user_id` from form params - doing so user will be able to pass some other user's id in form

Comment: That makes sense.  I would rather get the user from the controller than through hidden_fields..  I just tried to add it when i couldn't get it to work.

I still have the error though, when i try to display argument.user.first_name (or any other, except id)

Comment: Can it be because i am trying to access the devise usermodels data from another view?  I have been looking at the https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app
and helper methods

Comment: Yes, you can access devise user model from any view. You need to make sure that argument.user is not nil i.e. user_id is not nil in argument.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `argument` model has `belongs_to :user` you can assign `@argument.user = current_user` instead of id. Since `current_user` is already loaded overhead is minimal plus it will be available to `argument` without reload

Not related to problem, but need fixing:

1. Two calls to `save`/`save!` is strange, usually you want only one, especially when later in code you check if save was a success (now you'll have an exception on validation error instead of form render)
2. `argument_params` call is replaced with `params[:argument].permit(:argument)` (will yield error about `nil` instead of required params if you encounter a request without an `argument`)
3. `user_id` hidden field is discarded by strong parameters anyway, better to remove it (and not allow possible imposters)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and heads up :)
I still get the error when with the @argument.user = current_user ... 
To me it seems like the user params are not passed correctly with the creation of the argument ?

Comment: yes.  When i add <%= argument.user_id %> to my view i get the correct id of the user.